# Black Friday Pricing Setup

Tags: product, price

Is there a way to add a "Black Friday Promotion" with sale priced products, AND percentages off for entire categories AND free shipping but be ONE single promotion in the "Shopping Cart Rules?"

If not, how would you do something like that? Would each sale priced thing be all different promotions?

We just don't want to do a blanket 10% off or whatever but still want to for certain areas and have specific prices to specific products for the day.

Answer (score 2):

These are pretty creative promotions but you won't be able to do it with one single rule. The best way to do it is the following:

### % off Category

Use Catalog Price rules. Set it by category. Make sure to click "Save and Apply". Reindex and clear caches.

### Sale Priced Products

You can do this in multiple ways:

- Items that are priced with the "special price" price type and an applicable date within the Catalog product itself.
- Items that have a catalog pricing rule applied
- Coupon Code (shopping cart price rule)
- Automatic discount in the cart (shopping cart price rule with no coupon necessary)
- Discount based on customer group or segment (Magento EE only)

My suggestion is to use a coupon. This helps apply the next part:

### Free Shipping

Free shipping can be applied in the cart whenever a promotion that activates it is applied. This can be applied with or without a coupon code. My suggestion is to use a coupon code. This helps you distinguish orders with abnormally low AOV (as if shopping at the end of November weren't clue enough) in your reports.

HTH!